# Disable save as image on smartphones using all browsers ( chrome, firefox, ie, cm, opera )

Tags: images, mobile, customization, android

i want to disable the option to save as images on smartphones (android and IOS) using mobile browsers like chrome, firefox, ie, cm, opera, ie. Could anyone have a solution to this?
chi

Answer (score 1):

These days it is not really possible anymore to distinguish between mobile and other browsers, but you may try [`wp_is_mobile`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile). There are plugins that try to do a better job.

Then, if the user agent is mobile you may try to disable saving of the image, but there is no definite way to do this. To display the image it must be sent to the smartphone. You cannot take over the smartphone, so the user will always have methods to wrestle the image from you.

That said, there are methods to make it difficult for users. The most obvious one is to set images as backgrounds with css. This disables the normal way of saving images. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page) are some other options.